# PC Lint Warning 537: Repeated include file

Tags: c, lint, pc-lint

How to deal with this warning from PC Lint?

I have in several files the `#include <GenericTypeDefs.h>`. PC Lint shows me the message `Warning 537: Repeated include file 'filepath\filename.h'` If I delete this declaration I cannot compile.

I would like to suppress this warning if possible.

You can see the same reported [here](http://www.gimpel.com/Discussion.cfm?ThreadMode=Next&ThreadID=3145).

This is my code, for which my compiler emits warnings:

**`checksum.h`**

```
#ifndef CHECKSUM_H
#define CHECKSUM_H

#include <GenericTypeDefs.h>

BOOL isCheckSumCorrect(const UINT8 *dataPointer, UINT8 len, UINT8 checkSumByte);

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

**`cryptography.h`**

```
#ifndef CRYPTOGRAPHY_H
#define CRYPTOGRAPHY_H

#include <GenericTypeDefs.h>

UINT8 encrypt(UINT8 c);
UINT8 decrypt(UINT8 c);

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

**`crc8.h`**

```
#ifndef CRC_H
#define CRC_H

#include <GenericTypeDefs.h>

UINT8 generateCRC(const UINT8 *ptr, UINT8 Len);
BOOL isCRCValid(const UINT8 *ptr, UINT8 Len, UINT8 CRCChar);

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

Obviously, I didn't repeat `#include <GenericTypeDefs.h>` on `checksum.c`, `cryptography.c` and `crc8.c`

Comment: Show the code, trying to answer is useless without it.

Comment: @Griwes, I've linked an example about the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried doing what is suggested in the thread? Check the header guard before you #include the file, i.e. in crc.h you would do #ifndef generictypes_h #include <GenericTypeDefs.h> #endif. It's duplicated effort but it's maybe the only way.

Comment: In the context of the computing world, my brain is incapable of thinking of any "Alice" as a real person.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal You're right. I remove this info

Comment: @tinman Yes, I've tried this. It suppress most of warnings, but not all of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Just ignore it

If you have include guards, this is a spurious warning and can (should) be ignored. We use include guards because allowing a file to be included multiple times is good practice, enabling more flexible code, prevents human errors, and avoids having order significance in your `#include` statements.  If you want to know why this is the case, read on.

### Multiple includes aren't a problem because you have include guards.

Since these .h files are all pretty related, I'm guessing that you include all three in the same file somewhere, perhaps `main.c`:

```
#include "checksum.h"
#include "cryptography.h"
#include "crc8.h"

main () { /* Do Stuff */ }
```

This will be expanded (minus the comments, of course) to:

```
// CHECKSUM_H is not defined, so the preprocessor inserts:
#include <GenericTypeDefs.h>
BOOL isCheckSumCorrect(const UINT8 *dataPointer, UINT8 len, UINT8 checkSumByte);

// CRYPTOGRAPHY_H is not defined, so the preprocessor inserts:
#include <GenericTypeDefs.h>
UINT8 encrypt(UINT8 c);
UINT8 decrypt(UINT8 c);

// CRC_H is not defined, so the preprocessor inserts: 
#include <GenericTypeDefs.h>
UINT8 generateCRC(const UINT8 *ptr, UINT8 Len);
BOOL isCRCValid(const UINT8 *ptr, UINT8 Len, UINT8 CRCChar);

main () { /* Do Stuff */ }
```

So yes, `#include <GenericTypeDefs.h>` does appear multiple times at some point in the preprocessor step.  Ostensibly, the file looks something like:

```
#ifndef GENERIC_TYPE_DEFS_H
#define GENERIC_TYPE_DEFS_H

#define UINT8 unsigned char

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

so, after more preprocessing, our previously expanded bit (minus the comments) becomes:

```
// GENERIC_TYPE_DEFS_H is not defined, so the preprocessor inserts:
#define UINT8 unsigned char
BOOL isCheckSumCorrect(const UINT8 *dataPointer, UINT8 len, UINT8 checkSumByte);

// GENERIC_TYPE_DEFS_H IS defined, so the preprocessor inserts nothing.
UINT8 encrypt(UINT8 c);
UINT8 decrypt(UINT8 c);

// GENERIC_TYPE_DEFS_H IS defined, so the preprocessor inserts nothing.
UINT8 generateCRC(const UINT8 *ptr, UINT8 Len);
BOOL isCRCValid(const UINT8 *ptr, UINT8 Len, UINT8 CRCChar);

main () { /* Do Stuff */ }
```

Further preprocessing (not shown) copies the `#define` throughout the code.

### You are guaranteed to have include guards if you heed other preprocessor and linter warnings

The linter will warn you (errors 451 and 967) if any `.h` files lack standard include guards.  The compiler will warn about duplicate symbol definitions if the multiply-included `GenericTypeDefs.h` doesn't have include guards.  If it does not, either create your own `MyGenericTypeDefs.h` or switch to the [`<stdint.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/stdint.h.html) header, which is part of the C standard and provides similar functionality as your `GenericTypeDefs.h`.

### Warning: Bad workaround ahead

If you really insist on fixing the warning instead of ignoring it, you will have to remove `#include <GenericTypeDefs.h>` from each of the `.h` files and enter it once before one or more of these files are included, like this:

`checksum.c`

```
#include <GenericTypeDefs.h>
#include "checksum.h"
```

`cryptography.c`

```
#include <GenericTypeDefs.h>
#include "cryptography.h"
```

`crc.c`

```
#include <GenericTypeDefs.h>
#include "crc.h"
```

`main.c`

```
#include <GenericTypeDefs.h>
#include "checksum.h"
#include "cryptography.h"
#include "crc8.h"

main () { /* Do Stuff */ }
```

This is Not Recommended, as it results in more work for you and more chances for you to make mistakes (no offense, but you're only human and the preprocessor is not).  Instead, just ask the preprocessor to do its job and use the include guards the way they were designed.

Comment: Hi, @kevin! Glad to see you here too. Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the warning just for that header with the option:

```
-efile(537,GenericTypeDefs.h)
```

and add that to your Lint config if you have one.

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. This answers the original question of how to suppress the lint warning. In general it is good to suppress individual warnings that you have vetted so that the linter can find future warnings of the same type. The accepted answer of "Just ignore it" is akin to ignoring compiler warnings. If you just ignore these without addressing or suppressing them, then the helpful warnings will get lost in a sea of ignored warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The article you linked to explains that it's more of a PCLint oddity, that should be a Note rather than a Warning.

Just ignore it / disable it.